# I have a Form where two text inputs are there. when user enter text in one input and goes to other the text vanishes . what to do?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Form where two text inputs are there. when user enter text in one input and goes to other the text vanishes . what to do ?there are four dart files main.dart,new_transaction.dart,

the form module

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class NewTransaction extends StatelessWidget {
  final titleController = TextEditingController();
  final amountController=TextEditingController();
  final Function addTx;
  NewTransaction(this.addTx);
  void submitData()
  {
    final enterTitle =titleController.text;
    final enterAmount=double.parse(amountController.text);
    if (enterTitle.isEmpty||enterAmount<=0)
    {return;}
      addTx(enterTitle,enterAmount);
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 

        Card(
              elevation: 7,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'title'),
                      controller: titleController,
                      onSubmitted:(_)=>submitData(),
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'amount'),
                      controller: amountController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      onSubmitted:(_)=>submitData(),

                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      onPressed: submitData,
                     
                      
                      child: Text('Add Transaction'),
                      textColor: Colors.purple,
                    ),
                    
                  ],
                ),
              ));      
    
  }
}
```

i am calling this from Main like this
[main.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaJG8.png)

Comment: Please add your `main.dart` code in code format, it's little bit difficult if you provide it in the image format.

Comment: stackoverflow says this is so much code canot post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because `NewTransaction` is `StatelessWidget`. When `setState` is called from its parent `titleController` and `amountController` will be recreated. So the value will be empty.

**Solution:**

Make `NewTransaction` as `StatefulWidget`.

**Explanation:**

`StatefulWidget` have state for them (Kind of separate runtime memory block storage to store values of the variables). So even if the parent widget rebuilds, this `State` of the `StatefulWidget` won't be recreated. It will be just reused with previous persisted values.

But `StatelessWidget` don't have State (Won't maintain values of the variable). So if parent widget get rebuilds, then this `StatelessWidget` also rebuild. which means all the variable like `titleController` and `amountController` will be deleted and recreated(with empty values).

Comment: can you explain bit ? so we  do not want the NewTransaction  to recreate then why stateful?

Comment: @BiswajitJena I added the explanation. The explanation may have some mistakes, but i am sure `StatefulWidget` is what you need.

Comment: But the parent wizad here MyHomePage which is in main() , that only rebuilts when the form is submited . before submiting why it will affect titleController  and  amountController ?

Comment: @BiswajitJena We can't be sure only its rebuilds when calling `setState` explicitly, Flutter itself sometime try to rebuild (or refresh) whole tree widget.

Comment: I experienced this anonymous rebuilds lot when changing text in text fields or submitting it or on focus gain/lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
class _NewTransactionState extends State<NewTransaction> {
  String title = "";

  int amount = 0;

  void submitData() {
    if (title == "" || amount <= 0) {
      print("Invalid");
      //TODO:Handle invalid inputs
      return;
    }
    widget.addTx(title, amount);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Card(
            elevation: 7,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'title'),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      title = value;
                    },
                    onSubmitted: (_) => submitData(),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'amount'),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    onSubmitted: (_) => submitData(),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      amount = int.parse(value);
                    },
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: submitData,
                    child: Text('Add Transaction'),
                    textColor: Colors.purple,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this will work for you if not then tell me know in comment.

Comment: Using controllers is more cleaner way but you use fields also if you only preserving the value

Comment: Controllers provide better control but if you not using to much then use simple field for values.